# what does <Directory /> do?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I am new to apache. I want to understand httpd.conf and make a little change.

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/www"

<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The web app is located at /opt/www.
What is the aim of writing "`<Directory />..`"?
Does it handles some thing about permission visiting "/" on the server?

But *DocumentRoot* is set as /opt/www.
What about `<Directory "/var/www/html">`?

I am totally confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets the baseline for any directory that could be accessed by the configured site.

The set options will be inherited by elements inside those directories. You can then further define the configuration for nested elements. As it is done for `/var/www/html`. The major configuration change here seems to be the addition of the `Indexes` option for that directory (directories *above* it wouldn't have the option enabled).

In general, you will usually encounter two types of directives that *wrap* other directives in an Apache HTTPD configuration file. [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) and [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location).

In both cases, they will usually define a *scope* at which other directives are valid.

`<Directory>` refers to a location on your local file system. `<Location>` refers to a part of the URL used to access a certain location through the HTTPD.

To quote from the Apache HTTPD documentation:

> #### When to use `<Location>`
>
> Use `<Location>` to apply directives to content that lives outside the filesystem. For content that lives in the filesystem, use [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) and [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files). An exception is `<Location />`, which is an easy way to apply a configuration to the entire server.

Comment: Thank you! So I understand `<Directory />` is just an convenient way to set configurations to to inherited by all `<Directory ??>`s. Right? The server hosts only one site, and all HTMLs and PHPs are inside `/opt/www`, the DocumentRoot. What is possibly aim/use of `<Directory "/var/www/html">` based on your knowledge? Or it's just part of apache's default config without being touched by the admin?

Comment: @frozen-flame: Regarding the first part of your question, right, that's what it's for. Regarding the second part, if there is no `/var/www/html`, then the directive is pointless. The default configuration of the Apache HTTPD usually depends on the distribution you're using. Why this directive would be in the default configuration, I have no idea.